# Html Table: How to get the following output?

Tags: html, html-table

I have an image of a table design that looks like this
[Design of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zef0.jpg)

And my html code is

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="3">7</th>
      <th rowspan="3">6</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">2</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td colspan="2">8</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>         
</table>
```

But the table is being rendered in the following manner
[Output of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBzJa.jpg)

Any explanation why this is happening? and how to render like the above image

Answer (score 0):

use CSS grid styles
Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
.wrapper > div {
  border-style: solid;
}
.one {
  grid-column: 4/ span;
  grid-row: 3;
}
.two {
  grid-column: 1/ span 3;
  grid-row: 2/ span 2;
}
.three {
  grid-column: 5/ span 5;
  grid-row: 4;
}
.four {
  grid-column: 4/ span;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.five {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4;
}
.six {
  grid-column: 5/ span 5;
  grid-row: 1/ span 3;
}
.seven {
  grid-column: 1/ span 4;
  grid-row: 1 span;
}
.eight {
  grid-column: 2/ span 4;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
<div class="four">Four</div>
<div class="five">Five</div>
<div class="six">Six</div>
  <div class="seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="eight">Eight</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
table{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="github.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">7</th>
        <th rowspan="3">6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td colspan="2">8</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
table{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="github.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">7</th>
        <th rowspan="3">6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">2</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td colspan="2">8</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem you are facing is that you haven't set the width for your table. In the code examples that I attached above you can see one is similar to the one you don't want and the other to the one that you want as your output. The only difference is of widths.